# In SpriteKit, two spritenodes are not firing off contact event properly

Tags: sprite-kit, collision, contacts, skspritenode

I have two SKSpriteNode-s(let's call them SKSPriteNode A and SKSpriteNode B), A is my hero sprite and B is a scene element, and sometimes, the didBeginContact fires off when they collide and sometimes it doesn't. A has physicsBody set based on texture and B has rectangle based physicsBody set for it. I can see their textures collide and intersect but I don't see the NSLog fire off in the didBeginContact. This is not totally consistent because another time they collide and the contact event fires off just fine. I need this to be consistent, naturally. Anyone has a suggestion on this issue? The scene is the only contact delegate for the physicsWorld, so only the scene can trigger and go in the event handler, so I know it is working - at least some of the time. Code in scene:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"Contact happened!!!!!! :) ");
}
```

I have my custom class StaticLevelElement set so it extends SKSpriteNode:

```
@interface StaticLevelElement : SKSpriteNode
```

The B has been set as StaticLevelElement with a triangular image:

```
StaticLevelElement * B = [StaticLevelElement spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"triangle"];
```

I tried to set the B's physicsBody to have texture based physicsBody:

```
B.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"triangle"] size:B.size];
```

and I have the same result - intermittent contact, fires off occasionally, and not really consistent. Same happens if I set the B to have rectangle based physicsBody:

```
B.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:B.size];
```

Comment: You should post some code, details, screenshots, etc.. otherwise everyone who answers will just be guessing. Its really hard to say why its not working if we can't see what you've tried.

Comment: I will put a bounty on the question as soon as I am able(will be in two days).

Answer (score 0):

It is my opinion and I can say that with a medium level of certainty, that the anchorPoint caused this. I had it set to (0.5, 0) and that seemed to had caused this issue by, apparently, moving the whole physicsBody, which I dont like at all. Once I deleted this manual setting of anchorPoint (and thus returning it to (0.5, 0.5)), the contact looks like happening more or less properly. Still not perfect - not triggering for every time the overlap happens, but I think much better. As I said, I am still not completely clear on when does contact happens and how the anchorPoint influences it, but looks like it is.